# is it possible to create simple application without any theme?

Tags: vaadin

I am new to Vaadin. I wanted to create s simple page which should not have
any theme. When I run the simple application, it default takes reeinder theme.
So is it possible to create a simple theme without having any themes?
So it looks white background, normal html button, normal html labels,etc.
If needed, I shall use my own themes which could be created out of CSS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

it is possible to use a empty theme.
You must just create a empty css or sass file and then specify to use that theme.
You can then add the styles you need to the file.

You will then of course have to use the standard html buttons and so on.
The vaadin default buttons (and most components) depend on a proper theme.

This link might help you see what you will have to do when you wish to start with a completely new theme: https://vaadin.com/de/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+Theme+Tips+and+Tricks#section-Vaadin+Theme+Tips+and+Tricks-CreatingACompletelyNewLookNFeel

Perhaps starting with the base theme would be the middle way to go.

VAADIN/themes/base/styles.css

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will have look at it and come back!!

Comment: Definitely go with extending base. That will give you a set of css which makes everything work correctly without adding any visual rules. I you go with a whole clean css file, you would have to define a bunch of display, width, position etc. etc. for every single component to not look completely broken.